# SSIS DelayValidation randomly not working (Flatfile Connection Manager with Expression)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Have you ever had the weird behavior in SSIS 2008, that DelayValidation
on a Flatfile Connection Manager is randomly not working?

---

Here is the scenario I am struggeling with on SSIS 2008 (Non R2):

- my package covers the import of 30 different *.CSV flat files into the database
- CSV files are delivered each day to a dynamically created folder
  (D:\DataDelivery\DeliveryID_<GeneratedDeliveryID>)
  (e.g. "D:\DataDelivery\DeliveryID_73\", "D:\DataDelivery\DeliveryID_74\", ..)
  ==> from here the CSV files are imported via SSIS
- the delivery ID for the current import will be determined by a stored proc
  at the beginning of the SSIS package (stored into SSIS variable "iDeliveryID")
- based on the determined delivery ID we build the complete import path
  using a variable called "sImportPath" with an expression (EvaluateAsExpression=True):
  "D:\DataDelivery\DeliveryID_"+ (DT_WSTR, 1252)@[User::iDeliveryID] +"\"

..

- the generated import path is then used in an expression for the
  Connection property of each Flatfile Connection Manager, e.g.:

  - @[User::sImportPath]  +  "fileA.csv"
    (expression for the connection property in Connection Manager A)
  - @[User::sImportPath]  +  "fileB.csv"
    (expression for the connection property in Connection Manager B)
  - @[User::sImportPath]  +  "fileC.csv"
    (expression for the connection property in Connection Manager C)
- 
- the DelayValidation property of each Connection Manager is set to true!!!
- so for delivery ID 73 the connection properties of the Flatfile Connection Managers
  should at runtime resolve to:
      D:\DataDelivery\DeliveryID_73\fileA.csv
      D:\DataDelivery\DeliveryID_73\fileB.csv
      D:\DataDelivery\DeliveryID_73\fileC.csv

But this is what happens right now in reality:

- when running in Visual Studio then everything always runs fine as intended
- when running in production via SQL Server Agent, the following happens:

  - sometimes the package runs fine (all files imported)
  - sometimes fileA is imported correctly 
    while in the same process fileB stops with the message
    "Cannot open the datafile D:\DataDelivery\DeliveryID_0\fileB.csv"
    (error in pre-execute phase)
    => you see the delivery ID is 0 here 
    => obviously the expression was not resolving
  - sometimes fileB or fileC is imported correctly 
    while in the same process fileA stops with the message
    "Cannot open the datafile D:\DataDelivery\DeliveryID_0\fileA.csv"
    (error in pre-execute phase)
    => as you see the same error

==> in all cases the generated path (variable sImportPath) resolves correctly 
    (I am logging this)
==> But it seems to be that DelayValidation is randomly working for some of the 
    Connection Managers while it is not working for the others
==> I also tried to set DelayValidation=true for the whole package as well as for all 
    single tasks and containers ..still the same behaviour
Have you ever experienced such behaviour? If yes, then how did you deal with this?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.
Jens

Comment: Escape expression hell and build the import paths in a script task. Then you can step through to make sure the file paths are correct, validate that each file exists, log everything you're about to load, log errors when things are out of wack, throw exceptions, etc.

Comment: @brian thanks for your comment, but it stays still the same. The path itself must be correct anyway, as it is always at least one file where it is working correctly (just always a different file). I really think there must be something wrong with the DelayValidation behaviour, as the error states that it happens in the preexecution phase. And this should not happen when using DelayValidation.

Comment: A possible workaround. Use a script component source, that way you don't have to have a flat file connection manager. Essentially, it's just a stream reader feeding the buffer. http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/38-Script-Component-as-Source-SSIS.html

Comment: @brian thanks again for your ideas.  
however I found a solution, which is not really logical to me, but working.  
I just moved the concatenation of the @[User::iDeliveryID] from the variable @[User::sImportPath] expression into the connection expression of the Flatfile Connection Manager. Essentially the same logic but another place. Only MS knows why this is working while the other way is not working.  Anyway thanks a lot for your suggestions.